# XMLRPC Search product.template returns empty list

Tags: odoo-10, xml-rpc, odoo-12

I'm having trouble getting a list of records through xmlrpc from the product.template model.

This issue is only present in the product.template model and happens when I attempt to put a search domain in the search criteria.

```
# Gets the source records for the model we intend to migrate in the database class of script.
def get_records(self,model,filter,fields):
    return self.models.execute_kw(self.db, 1, self.password,model, 'search_read',filter,fields)

#method call
source_recs = source_db.get_records(source_model, [[[SYNC_FLAG,'=', 
    False]]] , source_fields)
```

The call to the model only works when the filter is [[]].  All other models run through this script without issue but the above script returns [] instead of a list of records as dictionaries.

Any help figuring out why I cannot use a filter/domain on the search function for product.template would be wonderful.

Comment: And what are the values of `SYNC_FLAG` and `model`? Is there a field named like the value of `SYNC_FLAG` in `module`? It seems that you are getting an empty response because of the domain.

Comment: `SYNC_FLAG = 'x_migrated'`
`model = 'product.template'`
however it doesn't really matter what I put into the domain,  I tried to run it with `[[['id','!=',False]]]`.  The only way it would run is with `[[]]`.

Comment: `search_read` is defined at line 4516 in `<path_to_v12>/odoo/models.py`. May I suggest putting a breakpoint there and debug?

Comment: @AdanCortes Thank you for pointing me in that direction. However the return is not making sense.  When I step my way through the `search_read` method the return line, if I run the code on it's own, returns a list of dictionaries.  however, during the `return [index[record.id] for record in records if record.id in index]` sometime between completion  of the method and actually getting the list the list empties.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Between the original call of `result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)` which calls the `search_read` method and the completion of `return [index[record.id] for record in records if record.id in index]`  the index does have a list of dictionaries, but when it comes back to the original `result` it's an empty list.  This is really confusing me.

Comment: What is the value of `index` at that point? If it is empty or otherwise has less values than you expect, trace back its assignment.

Comment: `index` has a full list of dictionaries for records initially pulled.

Comment: Ok, all, thank you for helping me with this.  Apparently the partner that helped us get started with odoo installed a module that extended search_read for both product_product and product_template which is causing the issue.

Comment: Anytime. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partner that originally installed and implemented Odoo in our system installed a custom module that extended search_read for products and templates.  This extension is what is clearing the list.  If anyone has worked with OSI and coming up with this issue the module is osi_default_product_category.